# Facebook "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream"?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload

after uploading an image, i want to post it on the users wall.
Unfortunately, i get the following error within a Facebook UI:

> "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream.*filepath*"

It seems that the value @"picture" won´t be accepted, but why?
When i NSLog the "thumbURL", its correct.
How can i fix that?
Here´s my complete method:

```
    NSString *thumbURL = kDefaultThumbURL;
    NSString *imageLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:[result objectForKey:@"link"]];    

    NSMutableDictionary* dialogParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             kAppId, @"app_id",
                             imageLink, @"link",
                             thumbURL, @"picture",
                             @"imageName", @"name",
                             nil];

    [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" 
                       andParams:dialogParams 
                     andDelegate:self];
```

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 7):

You need to store the image some where locally ,in a local server . due to this  [article](http://www.syndicatedmethods.com/SyndicatedBlogs/post/2010/06/22/FBCDN-image-is-not-allowed-in-stream-How-can-this-be.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this same issue by writing a page that just forwards the image data and then linking to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're not allowed sharing images hosted by Facebook CDN servers.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Download and host to image on your local server.
2. Write a page with gets the FBCDN url, gets the image content and send it returns the image data.