# How to add a picture to FBWebDialogs, using Facebook SDK 3.2

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am using the FBWebDialogs view for posting a message on your wall. This functionality is added to Facebook SDK 3.2

I am creating a multiplayer board game, and game invitations can be posted to your friends wall.
No I'd like to add a picture as well, the app logo.

The only thing I got working is the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
 @"Krudoku for iPhone, iPad and iPod touch", @"name",
 FBopponent.FBid, @"to",
 @"A multiplayer game which is a mixture of scrabble and sudoku.", @"caption",
 @"I'd like to play a game of Krudoku with you. Please go to the appstore and download Krudoku so we can play together!", @"description",
 @"http://www.facebook.com/Krudoku", @"link",
 @"http://www.krudoku.com/pictures/appicon_fb_136.png", @"picture",
 nil];

// Invoke the dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
{
 ....
 ....
 }];
```

The picture parameter refers to a picture on my web server. Now I would like to refer to a picture being saved on local device. But things like @"file://...." are not working.
Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must upload the picture to a web server and then using URL where you can access the uploaded picture, e.g.

```
http://www.myserver.com/uploads/myPicture.png
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546712/facebook-fbcdn-image-is-not-allowed-in-stream).

Comment: Can we add default comment to the params dictionary?just the way we are doing for name ,caption or picture.

Comment: You mean the default description? Like this: `NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"The default description to show.", @"description",
     nil];`